# Is there any US-wide collection of information about party strength in local elections?

Tags: united-states, election, local-government

In the US, is there anything like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_make-up_of_local_councils_in_the_United_Kingdom#Summary_of_councillors) list of the number of locally elected officials controlled by each party?

I am aware that there are a lot of nonpartisan officeholders in minor posts in America, and there is a bigger range of elected positions... but that just makes me more interested.

Comment: There are such lists for state-level elected positions, I don't know if there is one for city level positions though. Is that good enough for you?

Comment: I meant at the county level, but I'd certainly be interested in state level stuff

Comment: The secretary of state of each state maintains such a list. There is probably a document that consolidates that information.

Comment: Would you mind linking to one?

Comment: If I were an American citizen I would try asking to the people behind [USA.gov](https://www.usa.gov/contact/) website, which is an official website of the US government.

Comment: I surely ain't that. Good idea though

Comment: Bounty is still active. If someone can just link to a list of all local officials by party in a single state I'd probably award it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! The Republican State Leadership Committee, an organ of the Republican Party, maintain a handy list of which state offices are controlled by which party. You can find it here:
http://rslc.gop/map-center/

If you want actual lists of names of state elected officials, the way to find them is by googling the name of the body eg "california state legislature" and finding its official website.

This is perhaps beyond the scope of your question, but if you want to find more info on local/city elected officials, a good place to start though is by reading voter guides in the given states your interested in. They are published every year by each state's elections office and provide nonpartisan information on every office that is up for election, as well as biographies of candidates.

Here's an example of one from Washington State:
https://weiapplets.sos.wa.gov/MyVoteOLVR/OnlineVotersGuide/Measures?language=en&electionId=63&countyCode=xx&ismyVote=False&electionTitle=2016%20General%20Election%20

Hope this helps.

Comment: Those are handy maps, but the question is about local offices, not state offices.

Comment: Interesting, but that's state offices not local

Comment: The list you linked to tallied regional councils and did not include town councils. State government is the closest thing in the US to regional councils. Now if you really are interested in municipal and county government in the USA, ie city councils, county councils, prosecutors, treasurers etc then no publicly available list exists. Keep in mind, the US is a huge county and were talking about hundreds of thousands of individuals across 50 jurisdictions each with different rules. (edited b/c tempremental smartphone)

Comment: Actually, the number of elected officials in the United States according to the most recent census of local governments (I've only seen the print version) is about 30,000, of which about 4,000 are state and federal elected officials, and about 26,000 are local elected officials. Most municipal and school district and special district officials are non-partisan and most county officials are affiliated with a political party. There are about 3,000 counties in the U.S., and an average of about 5 partisan elected officials per county, so there are roughly 15,000 partisan local elected officials.

Comment: Actually, according to the Census bureau there were over 500,000 elected officials in the US as of 1992. It is true that many of these offices are technically nonpartisan, though it is important to note that this does not preclude the officials themselves from having a party affiliation. https://www.census.gov/prod/2/gov/gc/gc92_1_2.pdf

Comment: The list I linked to covers county, district and metropolitan. The only one it missed out are parish councils, which are usually nonpartisan, only cover a couple of hundred people and which aren't legally required to exist unless residents request one. Even the highest level (county) is no more powerful than US counties. Only the devolved govs of Wales, Scotland, NI are comparable to state governments.